# SQL error 1166 when using concat and substring/substring_index together in mysql

Tags: mysql

I met a strange error when using concat and substring_index together in mysql, my code is here

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE candidate (ori int, dest int, myPath varchar(500), depth int ) as (
    select transforms.ori, baseTransforms.dest, concat(substring_index(baseTransforms.road,',',-1),',',substring_index(transforms.road,',',1)), 2
    from transforms, baseTransforms
    where transforms.dest=baseTransforms.ori and transforms.ori <> baseTransforms.dest);
```

where definitions are here

```
create table baseTransforms(
    ori int,
    dest int,
    road varchar(500)
);
create table transforms(
    ori int,
    dest int,
    road varchar(500)
);
```

and baseTransform's data is filled like this

```
insert into baseTransforms select * from transforms;
```

Then I get

> Error Code: 1166. Incorrect column name 'concat(substring_index(baseTransforms.road,',',-1),',',substring_index(transforms.road,',',1))'

but when I modify the code by deleting one of my substring_index phase, it doesn't raise up an error, i.e.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE candidate (ori int, dest int, myPath varchar(500), depth int ) as (
        select transforms.ori, baseTransforms.dest, concat(',',substring_index(transforms.road,',',1)), 2
        from transforms, baseTransforms
        where transforms.dest=baseTransforms.ori and transforms.ori <> baseTransforms.dest);
```

and

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE candidate (ori int, dest int, myPath varchar(500), depth int ) as (
        select transforms.ori, baseTransforms.dest, concat(substring_index(baseTransforms.road,',',-1),','), 2
        from transforms, baseTransforms
        where transforms.dest=baseTransforms.ori and transforms.ori <> baseTransforms.dest);
```

both works well, so in fact both column names are right ,it's so confusing.

p.s. when I try to use substring function instead of substring_index , it got the same problem.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Column names can be a maximum of 64 characters long](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html), but your `CONCAT` expression (which, by default, becomes the column name in your subquery) exceeds that.

You could put `AS path` (or similar) after it, to give the column a fixed, short name.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know the result of concat expression will become the column name by default before.